# Can I make a mdadm raid on a file, not a block device?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I would like to play with `mdadm`, the Linux RAID system. I want to see what happens when you fail a drive, when you grow the raid etc etc. My initial thought was to create 4 equally sized files (`fallocate -l 100M ./diskN`), and then play with `mdadm`. But mdadm doesn't like working just with files:

```
# mdadm --create ./raiddisk1 ./disk1 ./disk2  --level=1 --raid-devices=2
mdadm: ./disk1 is not a block device.
```

Is it possible to use `mdadm` on files? In Unix, everything's supposed to be a file, right?

This is Linux 4.15.0-70-generic from an Ubuntu Linux 18.04.3 (bionic), with `mdadmn --version` saying `v4.1-rc1 - 2018-03-22`.

Comment: About 80% sure I played around with this in the based by setting the files up as a loop device (`losetup`).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302766/persistent-use-of-loop-block-device-in-mdadm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519761/programming-a-loopback-device-consisting-of-several-files-in-linux